# Filter data frame based on a test match in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I want to filter all the rows where any of the following appear in a column:

```
Word_List = ["XXX", "Transfer", "Do not use"]
```

I want to be able to ignore the case too.  In R I would have used grepl for this task but I can't find an equivalent in Python.

Comment: Basically you can `df[df['col'].str.lower().isin(Word_List)]`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you!